# Black screen during requests for ios 9 - PromiseKit?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, promisekit

When I updated xCode and build on iOs 9, during all my synchronisation requests, my screen is black. It is working, but it seems that threads are not handled the same way. I am using AFNetworking and PromiseKit pods.

I did not updated PromiseKit  (my current version is 1.6.0) because the last version is in Swift and I have an error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/[user]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromiseKit.framework/PromiseKit
>     Reason: image not found

For that error I tried

- Runpath Search Paths

  `$(inherited)
   @executable_path/Frameworks
   @loader_path/Frameworks`
- Embedded Content Contains swift Code to 'YES'
- 'OU' parameter in my certificates
- updating cocoapods, xcode
- deleting derived datas, reinstalling my pods, cleaning

Do you think black screen could be fixed only by updating PromiseKit or could be another reason? Do you have any idea how to fix libSwiftCore issue ? Thanks !

Comment: Don't know about the black screen, but did you try adding use_frameworks! To your pod file?

Comment: Yes I put it before pod install